# Website <footer> displaying in a fixed position when no position:fixed in CSS

Tags: css, css-position, footer

On [this page](http://www.annsstudioofdance.com/about-us), the `<footer>` element is displaying in a fixed position.  The footer is cutting off the main content div.  This is unintended.

Other pages on the website do not have the footer cutting off the content div.

Using Google Chrome code inspector, when I highlight the footer

```
<footer class="container_wrap socket_color" id="socket" role="contentinfo" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
```

There is no display:fixed or display:absolute for `<footer>`.

I've had a look at the page in Wordpress admin, and there is nothing out of the ordinary with the way it is setup.

Can you see if this is CSS causing this effect?  Thank you.

Comment: It's not displaying with `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove these from #main

- position: relative;
- z-index: 2;
- overflow: hidden;

remove these from #av_section_1

- height: 287px;

Dont know why have you used z-index everywhere and also used overflow:hidden on your main div. The above changes will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your CSS you have `height: 287px;` on the `#av_section_1` rule (*which is your `div` with the main content of that page*)..

If you remove that it works just fine..